# Open3D WARNING Read PLY failed: unable to read file

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I'm facing an issue regarding reading `.ply` files. I double-checked that the file's path is correct. The code raises a warning and continues running. However, the results of the processing made on the `cloud` variable empty.

```
import open3d as o3d
cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("aaa.ply")
```

> [Open3D WARNING] Read PLY failed: unable to read file: aaa.ply
> RPly: Aborted by user

I'm using the version `0.17.0` of Open3D.

**Update:**

[Link to the `.ply` file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OuFkeUZotm34VkbQvb0sb_wYE9pCnby_/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 2):

It might be a problem with your `.ply` file, try with one from [here](https://www.artec3d.com/3d-models) or share your `aaa.ply` file with us.

Also, you can have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/3415).

**EDIT**
After you provided the .ply file, indeed it seems to be throwing that warning, but I can access the points in the point cloud:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud('aaa.ply')
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([cloud])
cloudPoints = np.asarray(cloud.points)
```

Comment: I updated the post with a link to the `.ply` file.

Comment: Well, it seems to work, even though it keeps throwing that warning message. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do you think that may be an issue, or should I ignore it?

Comment: I think you can ignore it. As long as you can access the points, the colors and everything else that is stored in that `.ply` file it shouldn't be a problem. (Don't want to be a hater or something, but from my experience of working with open3d, this is a very, very changing library from one version to another (including function names and import paths) so this might be just a misplaced warning left over.) :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but slightly different error: "open3d .ply Read PLY failed: no vertex attribute", so this may help you.  The .ply file I was using was part of the [DALES](https://udayton.edu/engineering/research/centers/vision_lab/research/was_data_analysis_and_processing/dale.php) lidar dataset.  Open3d expects the files have elements named "vertex" and "face" apparently.  I found that my .ply files had elements named "testing" in the header.

**How to check element types**
Open the file in a text editor, or just use command line to see the top 10 or so lines

Inside :

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element testing 11331760  # This needs to be "vertex" or "face" not "testing"
property float x
property float y
property float z
property int intensity
property int sem_class
property int ins_class
end_header
```

You may be able to manually type and save it.  I had several files to change, so used this code to convert all elements to "vertex".  This would be bad if you had a mix of vertexes and faces.  My data are pointclouds, so everything is a vertex.

**Change element types**

To convert a single file to type "vertex" with python:

```py
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyProperty, PlyElement
from pathlib import Path

# read in file
data = PlyData.read("orig_file.ply")
# make a new PlyElement with type "vertex" with our existing data
renamed_element = PlyElement.describe(data.elements[0].data, 'vertex',
                        comments=[f'Renamed from: {data.elements[0].name}'])
# Make a new PlyData object of binary format 
fixed_data = PlyData([renamed_element], text=to_ascii)
# Write it out
fixed_data.write("Fixed_file.ply")
```

Answer (score 0):

After making the changes, I found that it was indeed possible

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element vertex 164397
comment Renamed from: params
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property char label_ch
property char label_mono
end_header
```